# My search function is not working because there is something wrong with my if statement,and I'm using linked list

Tags: c, if-statement, linked-list

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

void new_contact();//add contact using linked list
void list_contact();
void delete_contact();

//int sorting_contact();//sort contact name using sorting
void search_contact();//search for contact phone number using searching

struct contact
{
    char phone_number[20];
    char contact_name[70];
    char address [80];
    struct contact *ptrnext;
};

struct contact *headptr, *newptr, *currentptr, *previousptr;

int main()
{
    system("color B");
    int key;
    char ch;
    int choice=TRUE;
    headptr=(struct contact *)NULL;

    while(choice==TRUE)
    {

        printf("\n\t\tWelcome to Smart Phone Book System");
        printf("\n\nAdd a contact :A\nList a contact :L\nDelete a contact :D"
               "\nSearch for contact :S\nSort phonebook :T\nExit :x\n");
        printf("\nPlease enter the mode you want:");
        scanf(" %c%*c", &ch);
        switch(ch)
        {
            case 'A': new_contact();system("CLS");break;

            case 'L': system("CLS");list_contact();break;

            case 'D': system("CLS");delete_contact();break;

            case 'S': search_contact();break;
            //case 'T': sorting_contact(); break;

            case 'X': choice=FALSE; break;

            default: system("CLS");printf("\nPlease enter a proper mode");
        }
    }
}

void new_contact()//add data
{
    newptr=(struct contact *)malloc(sizeof (struct contact)); // pointer to a new
                    //  memory allocation

    if (headptr==(struct contact *)NULL)//node is empty?
    {
         headptr=newptr; //first pointer point to first node
         newptr->ptrnext=(struct contact *)NULL; //first node pointer point to null
    }
    else
    {
         newptr->ptrnext=headptr;// new node pointer point to previous first node
         headptr=newptr; // head point to new node,new node become first node
    }
    printf("\nEnter a new name : ");
    fgets( newptr->contact_name,sizeof(newptr->contact_name),stdin);
    printf("\nEnter a number : ");
    fgets(newptr->phone_number,sizeof(newptr->phone_number),stdin);
    //scanf(" %d", &newptr->phone_number);
    //getchar();
    printf("\nEnter address : ");
    fgets(newptr->address,sizeof(newptr->address),stdin);
}

void list_contact()
{
    int i=1;
    if (headptr==(struct contact*)NULL) //empty list
    {
        printf("\nEmpty list");
        return;
    }

    currentptr=headptr;
    do
    {
        printf("\nContact  number %d",i);
        printf("\nName : %s", currentptr->contact_name);
        printf("\nPhone number : %s", currentptr->phone_number);
        printf("\n\nAddress : %s", currentptr->address);

        i++;
        printf("\n");
        currentptr=currentptr->ptrnext; //point to next node
    }

    while(currentptr !=(struct contact *)NULL);
}

void delete_contact()
{
    char contact_name_delete[20];

    if (headptr==(struct contact *)NULL)//node is empty?
    {
        printf("\n\nThe list is empty. Cannot delete!!!\n");
        //inform the user that the list is empty
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nDelete list by name.");
        printf("\nEnter contact name to delete: ");
        fgets(contact_name_delete,sizeof(contact_name_delete),stdin);

        currentptr=headptr;

        while(currentptr ->ptrnext!=(struct contact *)NULL)
        {

            if (strncmp(currentptr->contact_name,contact_name_delete,6)==0) 
            //found the location
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                previousptr=currentptr;//save the previous current address
                currentptr=currentptr->ptrnext; 
                //point to next node
            }
        }

        if (strncmp(currentptr->contact_name,contact_name_delete,6)==0)
        {
            if ( currentptr==headptr) //number is the first and only node in list
            {
                headptr=currentptr ->ptrnext; //head point to NULL
                free(currentptr);
            }
            else //delete at the middle of link list
            {
                previousptr->ptrnext=currentptr->ptrnext;
                free(currentptr);//destroy  node, free the memory.
            }
            printf("\nPhone number were deleted!\n");
        }
        else
            printf("\nNumber to be deleted is not in the list!!! ");
    }
}
```

My problem is in the `search_contact()` function:

```
void  search_contact()//The function for searching the contact based on name
{
    currentptr=headptr;
    char contact_name_add[30];
    if (headptr ==(struct contact *)NULL)
    {
        printf("The phonebook is empty..");
    }
    else
    {

        printf("Please enter the name of your contact for searching : ");//user inputs name for searching
        fgets(contact_name_add,sizeof(contact_name_add),stdin);//uses linear search concept

        printf("\n\nThe computer will now search for your contact");

        do
        {
            if (strncmp(currentptr->contact_name,contact_name_add,5)==0)
            {
                printf("\nName :         %s", currentptr->contact_name);
                printf("\nPhone Number : %s",currentptr->phone_number);
                printf("\nAddress :      %s", currentptr->address);
                currentptr=currentptr->ptrnext;
            }
            else
            {
                currentptr=currentptr->ptrnext;
```

I've found out that the line below is my problem, but I don't know why

```
                if (currentptr->ptrnext=NULL
                    && strncmp(currentptr->contact_name,contact_name_add,5)!=0)
                {
                    printf("\nThe name you seek is not in the phonebook~~");
                }
            }
        } while(currentptr!=(struct contact *)NULL);
    }
}
```

I can search my contact that I've inserted just fine, but the problem exists when I have 2 or more contacts. The search function is quite similar to my delete function, but I've coded it to display more that 1 contacts (in the case of similar contact names), but when it reaches NULL, it gives out an error, and I could not find it on Google (my bad on that part).

Comment: Is it possible to prune out the unnecessary bits and clean up the formatting a bit? If you're just asking about the if-statement, I doubt all of that code is necessary to show the problem you're having.

Comment: Sorry I just thought maybe you would want to run the code for yourself,besides,I'm still new at formatting my code,I know I should be good at that

Comment: I agree that being able to run the code and see the issue is good. I'm just saying if we do that there's parts of the code that you already know can't be related. So go ahead and remove those. (Who knows, you might actually find the issue while you're removing unnecessary bits)

Comment: @DennisMeng thanks for the advice.Anyway,when I remove the If condition
    'code' if   (currentptr->ptrnext=NULL
        &&strncmp(currentptr->contact_name,contact_name_add,5)!=0)
    'code'

my program runs just fine,without any sudden error and breakdowns

Comment: When you want us to compile the code, make it copy-and-pasteable. That is, make it one big chunk of code and don't intersperse it with "This is my search function" and such; this is what comments in the code are for.

Comment: Please see how to create an MCVE ([How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) or
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)) — two names, two web sites, same idea.  Your names etc include newlines because you use `fgets()` — mostly good! — but don't remove the newlines (probably you really want them removed in the long run).  It doesn't directly affect your problem, though.  (Providing an MCVE/SSCCE would make it easier for us to spot the problem.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't do assignments in your `if` statements!  The code reading:

```
if (currentptr->ptrnext=NULL
```

should be:

```
if (currentptr->ptrnext == NULL
```

With the assignment (single `=`), the result of the assignment is false, so the second half of the conditional — the `strncmp()` — is never executed.

If you use GCC, you should be using options so that it warns you about such problems — `-Wall` would be sufficient for that warning.  I routinely use  this (or `-std=c11` and the other options):

```
gcc -g -O3 -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes \
    -Wold-style-definition -Wold-style-declaration -Werror ...
```

Your code would not compile under those options.

---

Given the claim made in comments that the assignment is a typo, then the rest of the problem is the logic.  The loop as currently written is, when presented more legibly:

```
    do
    {
        if (strncmp(currentptr->contact_name, contact_name_add, 5) == 0)
        {
            printf("\nName :         %s", currentptr->contact_name);
            printf("\nPhone Number : %s", currentptr->phone_number);
            printf("\nAddress :      %s", currentptr->address);

            currentptr = currentptr->ptrnext;
        }
        else
        {
            currentptr = currentptr->ptrnext;

            if (currentptr->ptrnext == NULL &&
                strncmp(currentptr->contact_name, contact_name_add, 5) != 0)
            {
                printf("\nThe name you seek is not in the phonebook~~");
            }
        }
    } while (currentptr != (struct contact *)NULL);
```

I don't trust bottom-testing loops; there are occasions when you need to go at least once through a loop, but lists can be empty and then you don't want to go through the body of the loop at all.

I'd probably use:

```
    while (currentptr != NULL)
    {
        if (strncmp(currentptr->contact_name, contact_name_add, 5) == 0)
        {
            printf("Name :         %s\n", currentptr->contact_name);
            printf("Phone Number : %s\n", currentptr->phone_number);
            printf("Address :      %s\n", currentptr->address);
            break;
        }
        currentptr = currentptr->ptrnext;
    }
    if (currentptr == NULL)
        printf("The name you seek (%s) is not in the phonebook\n", contact_name_add);
```

You might note that I end lines of output with a newline; I don't usually begin lines of output with a newline unless I want double spacing.  Your input code needs to be fixed to remove the newlines that `fgets()` keeps.  Write a function to call `fgets()` and strip the newline from the input.

> [Can you] modify the loop and give the search result in case of multiple same contact name?

*Of course. It is software; you can always change the spec and then change the code. You lose the break in the loop and count the matches and only report 'no match' if the count is zero after the loop.*

To print all matches:

```
    int counter = 0;
    while (currentptr != NULL)
    {
        if (strncmp(currentptr->contact_name, contact_name_add, 5) == 0)
        {
            printf("Name :         %s\n", currentptr->contact_name);
            printf("Phone Number : %s\n", currentptr->phone_number);
            printf("Address :      %s\n", currentptr->address);
            ++counter;
        }
        currentptr = currentptr->ptrnext;
    }
    if (counter == 0)
        printf("The name you seek (%s) is not in the phonebook\n", contact_name_add);
```

Comment: Sorry that was a mistake on my part,it was a typo.Regarding the code 
'IF (currentptr->ptrnext == NULL'
I still face the error when I have more than one contact

Comment: We can't debug code other than what you supply us in the question, can we?

Comment: brother(hope you don't mind),you are really good at this,thanks for showing me the way,I really appreciate it,and I picked your answer and to other users in this post,forgive me if I offended you in any way

Comment: I'm just wondering,is there any possibility for me to modify the loop and give the search result in case of multiple same contact name?Just asking

Comment: Of course. It is software; you can always change the spec and then change the code. You lose the `break` in the loop and count the matches and only report 'no match' if the count is zero after the loop.

Comment: Based on your suggestion,I'm guessing I should create a new variable such as  "match_count"?and when I have a match it increases?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following IF:

```
if(currentptr->ptrnext==NULL && strncmp(currentptr->contact_name,contact_name_add,5)!=0)
```

Comment: Correct, but maybe you should explain what was wrong before?

Comment: so...where should I put it?since the code you wrote is the same as my code

Comment: @HafizSyazwan: no, it isn't the same...Look carefully at the number of `=` signs before the `NULL` in the code above compared to your code where you identify the problem occurs.  The assignment `currentptr->ptrnext = NULL` is always false, so the comparison with `strncmp()` is never made, so …

Comment: What you are doing in your if statement is an assignment, because you are using just one equal sign "=". But you want to do a comparison, so use "==". My if is different from yours, pay attention.

Comment: @use44855 I know its different,it was a typo when I edited my post.But I still face runtime error when I have more that two contact,and I try the search function